# How to fail a Test in ScalaTest and print stacktrace?

Tags: scala, scalatest

In ScalaTest, I fail a test by:

```
fail("message")
```

It only prints message in a red highlight but does not print stacktrace.

I had to do a very awkward way like:

```
try { throw new Exception } catch { case e => 
  e.printStackTrace()
  fail("message")
}
```

to get the stacktrace.

I tried to do `fail("message", new Exception)` and it does not print either. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following ways:

```
fail(new Exception().getStackTrace.foldLeft("")(_ + " " + " " + _))
```

It will print out the stackTrace concatenated with spaces( or whatever way you want to concatenate)

```
fail(new Exception().getCause)
```

Or this to get the cause of the exception

Both ways are fine, depending on exactly what you want.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks. Surprisingly ScalaTest doesn't have an "out-of-box" solution for this.

Answer (score 5):

Reporters may be [configured](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner#configuringReporters) to show short or full stack traces via configuration parameters

```
S - show short stack traces
F - show full stack traces
```

For example, configuring short stack traces on standard output in `build.sbt` like so

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-oS")
```

then the following test

```
import org.scalatest._

class HelloSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "The Hello object" should "say hello" in {
    fail("boom!")
  }
}
```

outputs something like

```
[info] HelloSpec:
[info] The Hello object
[info] - should say hello *** FAILED ***
[info]   boom! (HelloSpec.scala:7)
[info]   org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException:
[info]   ...
[info]   at example.HelloSpec.$anonfun$new$1(HelloSpec.scala:7)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
```

Comment: Thanks @mario-galic! To apply this across all modules in the build this would be: `ThisBuild / testOptions += ...`